# The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class MyApp error in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting the error `The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class MyApp error in Flutter` in the `onSubmitted` of the `TextField`

Code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String phoneNo;

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'SchoolTrack',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.grey[50],
      ),
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: null,

        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[100],

        body: new Container(

          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: new Center(
            child: new TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              autocorrect: false,


              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type the phone no',
                  suffixIcon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                  suffixStyle: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.cyan[300],
                  )
              ),

                onSubmitted: (String input) {
                  setState(() {
                    phoneNo = input;
                  });
                },

            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
   }
```

Comment: You need to create your own StatefulWidget, there you can call `setState`

Comment: Can we use setState method in Util class ?   Util class is not Stateful widget.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I assume you are trying to setState in a stateless widget, which is immutable(unable to change).

Use a stateful widget to do so, like this:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget{
  HomePage createState()=> HomePage();
}

class HomePage extends State<MainPage>{
 //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Hi Oush, may know why we need to do this 'class MainPage extends StatefulWidget{
  HomePage createState()=> HomePage();
}' I'm currently had issue this on the HomePage();

Comment: Hi @FoolBaby, `MainPage` was just an example here in this case

Comment: Yes, but you need: 

"class MainPage extends StatefulWidget{ HomePage createState()=> HomePage();}"

This because I don't add this the flutter still take SetSate as an undefined method, but I do add, it works

Answer (score 19):

place

> setState

inside

> StatefullWidget

:) that will solve the problem

Answer (score 15):

You have to call that function within a stateful widget

Answer (score 9):

`setState` is only available inside a `StatefulWidget` class/subclass. You need to convert your `StatelessWidget` to a `StatefulWidget`. Simply:

Click on the `StatelessWidget` class and use <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> (or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> if you use VS Code on macOS),

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Be Sure you typed right

```
setState( () {} ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, the issue stem from StatelessWidget. For people who use text editors for coding the easiest way is like following:
Replace this:

```
class YourClassName extends StatelessWidget {
```

With this:

```
class YourClassName extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourClassNameState createState() => _YourClassNameState();
}

class _YourClassNameState extends State<YourClassName> {
```

All other things will be the same and now you can call setState inside your class:

```
setState(() {
      whatever you want to update goes here
    });
```

However, it is more practical to put your setState inside your own function and trigger it from anywhere easily:

```
void funtionName(passing parameters) {
    setState(() {
      ....
    });
}
```

Now call your function easily from anywhere like: funtionName(parameter).

Answer (score 2):

setState{} is only available inside a Stateful Widget class/subclass. You need to convert your Stateless Widget to a StatefulWidget.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a lambda and getting 'setstate isn't referenced' be sure to type it right with the brackets:

```
setState(() => _counter++);
```

instead of:

```
setState() => _counter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the cursor above the `StatelessWidget` and press `Alt + insert` and click on convert to `StatefulWidget`, to quickly covert your `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`.