# How do I make my text selectable and change title color?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make the `ListView` text selectable and have the first text be the default. I want it to look like the text below the Discover text: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/2884070/screenshots/12198574/media/cfe620d3b9b4e5f6665cb00703b92101.png

This is what I have:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/626321327791538188/725049838793654405/img1.PNG

Here is the code for the section I want:

```
Widget catagoriesSection = Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(236, 239, 248, 1),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(45.0)),
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 5, 30, 0),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
                height: 350,
                child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _buildTravelName(categories[0]),
                      SizedBox(width: 40),
                      _buildTravelName(categories[1]),
                      SizedBox(width: 40),
                      _buildTravelName(categories[2])
                    ])))
      ],
    ));

Widget _buildTravelName(String title) {
return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      print("Button pressed");
    },
    child: Text(title,
        style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(139, 98, 168, .4))));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable to keep track of which category is clicked. I also changed your function parameter so we can use the index to get the title text and the position in the categories list. Apply the decoration the same way like fontWeight below.

```
int _currentCat = 0;
Widget _buildTravelName(int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
            setState(() => _currentCat = index);
            print("Button pressed");
        },
        child: Text(categories[index],
            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: _currentCat == index ? FontWeight.w600 : FontWeight.bold,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(139, 98, 168, .4))));
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying setState is not defined. I did what this post said: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597189/the-method-setstate-isnt-defined-for-the-class-myapp-error-in-flutter. Now I am getting an exception: type 'MyApp' is not a subtype of type 'StatelessWidget' in type cast. Do you have a solution?

Comment: if you're using visual studio code, you can right click on StatelessWidget and select Refactor to convert from stateless to stateful widget