# BottomSheet value does not update using button flutter

Tags: flutter, button, bottom-sheet, statefulwidget

I have a Bottom Sheet which has sets of buttons. I use the buttons to change the value of `pinString` and a text to show the `pinString`. The value of the text does not update when button is clicked. How to fix this

```
  showNumberPad(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
          return Container(
            height: 550.0,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "$pinString",
                ),
                KeyboardNumber(
                  n: 1,
                  onPressed: () {
                     pinIndexSetup("1");
                     setState1() {
                       pinString = "New Pin";
                     }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

KeyboardNumber is a custom Stateful widget where I want to pass the onPressed as a parameter.
Code for keyboardNumber:

```
class KeyboardNumber extends StatefulWidget {
  final int n;
  final onPressed;

  const KeyboardNumber({Key key, this.n, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _KeyboardNumberState createState() => _KeyboardNumberState();
}

class _KeyboardNumberState extends State<KeyboardNumber> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 60.0,
      height: 60.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: teal2,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        onPressed: widget.onPressed,
        height: 90.0,
        child: Text(
          "${widget.n}",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you define pinString in **another** state and change it in **bottomeSheet state**, you must define it in this line :

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        String pinString = 'hi';
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState){
          return Container(
            height: 550.0,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "$pinString",
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Update"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() => pinString = 'new');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: This error shows up
```
The declaration 'setState' isn't referenced.
Try removing the declaration of 'setState'.
```

Comment: I test it and do the trick with no error, what is your flutter version

Comment: @Nehal Please check my answer. I tested it and its working.

Comment: @Nehal `The declaration 'setState' isn't referenced.`  shows up because you're trying to call `setState` in an stateless widget ,make sure you are using stateful, check out this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597189/the-method-setstate-isnt-defined-for-the-class-myapp-error-in-flutter

Comment: Instead of FlatButton I use a custom Widget, it shows the same error "The declaration 'setState1' isn't referenced. Try removing the declaration of 'setState1'". I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the new `setState` will override your main widget `setState` but sure you can just rename it so you would be able to set state of your parent widget and the modal's

**Here is the updated code.**

```
showNumberPad(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, SetState1) {
          return Container(
            height: 550.0,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "$pinString",
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Update"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    SetState1(() {
                      pinString = "New Pin";
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Instead of FlatButton I use a custom Widget, it shows the same error "The declaration 'setState1' isn't referenced.
Try removing the declaration of 'setState1'"